# How to turn off Rebol3 terminal coloring?

Tags: rebol3

I'm on macos 10.15.7

using "Rebol/Bulk 3.15.0 (23-Nov-2023/18:23 UTC)"

from here:  https://github.com/Oldes/Rebol3/releases

Is there a way to turn off the fancy colors?

I use a light background color scheme and their theme does not work well with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to turn off console coloring in Rebol3?

***You cannot!***

The ANSI escape sequences are hard-coded through-out the source:

```
^[[1;32m--trace (-t)^[[m     Enable trace mode during boot
^[[1;32m--verbose^[[m        Show detailed startup information
```

Disgusting!

Comment: To add to my little rant... please see [no-color](https://no-color.org) which says "If your software outputs color by default, please consider not doing so. If you insist, please implement this standard to make it easy for your users to disable color..."